# Do iOS devices meant to have enterprise apps installed on them require any special configuration?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, provisioning

For example to deploy a test app on an iOS device the device requires a provisioning profile for the test app and the test app needs to have the device in its own provisioning profile.

Does this apply to enterprise apps or can I just compile an enterprise app using an enterprise provisioning profile and distribute it willynilly to all iOS devices?